# Error with multiple alert buttons and void

Tags: xcode, timer, alert, void

```
-(void)checkCollision{
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame, enemy.frame)) {

    [randomMain invalidate];
    [start setHidden:NO];

    CGRect frame = [player frame];
    frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
    frame.origin.y = 326.0;
    [player setFrame:frame];

    CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
    frame2.origin.x = 137.0f;
    frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
    [enemy setFrame:frame2];


    [randomMain invalidate];
    [start setHidden:NO];

    [timer invalidate];
    time.text = @"0";
```

Hello There, the problem I am facing is that I try and make an alert view below yet i get an error saying the following: Invalid argument type "void" to unary expression. on the line reading:    -(void) alert1:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)ButtonIndex {
Cheers

```
    time.text = @"0"; 
    [timer invalidate];




          NSString *timemessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unlucky! You survived for %i seconds!", timenumber];
              UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You've Been Caught!" message:timemessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Show Leaderboard", @"Submit To game Center",nil];
    [alert1 show];




              -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)ButtonIndex {
        if (ButtonIndex == 1) {
        GKScore *myScore = [[GKScore alloc]
                            initWithCategory:@"*****"];
            myScore.value = timenumber;



        }
        }










                }}
            ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)ButtonIndex {` is a start of a new method. It can't be enclosed inside `checkCollision`. You need to move it and all of its code outside. It can go right after the end of  `checkCollision` if you want. You also need to set the delegate of the UIAlertView to the object you want to receive the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` callback. Usually that is `self`. Something like this:

```
-(void)checkCollision {
    // Blah, blah, ....
    NSString *timemessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unlucky! You survived for %i seconds!", timenumber];
    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You've Been Caught!" message:timemessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:@"Show Leaderboard", @"Submit To game Center",nil];
    [alert1 show];
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)ButtonIndex {
    if (ButtonIndex == 1) {
        GKScore *myScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"*****"];
        myScore.value = timenumber;
    }
    // Handle other button choices ....
}
```

Comment: There are no errors but the buttons don't do anything and when you say all of its code, do you mean just the void alert view buttons or the initial alert to

Comment: yes but I've done the int timenumber; in the header file and tried doing what you did but it did not work, i was left with loads of errors

Comment: I meant the code as an example. You haven't given us all your code so we can't write out exactly the code you need. If you have timenumber in the header, then obviously you don't need it here. The point is that you need to create your `UIAlertView` as I've showed, then show it, then somewhere else in the class you need to implement `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`. If you are getting errors in those lines feel free to post them.

Comment: i now have no errors and I've copied your code but nothing happens when i touch the buttons???

Comment: When you say nothing happens do you mean the alert view never gets dismissed, or it just gets dismissed without doing anything? My code example does not show anything on screen when you push a button. You'll have to fill out the rest of the code for `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` to make it do what you want. You can add an `NSLog(@"Clicked something!")` statement at the beginning of the method to make sure it is being called when you click a button. If not you probably still have the delegate set incorrectly.